# SQL AG Listener behavior during Failover

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

We have a AG with 2 replicas in same subnet, AG listener configured and able to connect using Listener name.

Test Case 1 : We have connect SQL server using AG Listener name from SSMS executed a script with cursor (Created to run for long time) in the background initiated a Manual and automatic failover (Stopped SQL services on Primary Replica).

Observation : Our ongoing Query failed with below error, Is there any settings \ additional setup  need to continue ongoing transactions or it's limitation of AG where ongoing transactions will killed \ Rollbacked

**Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.**

Note : We are facing same issue with Application also, When ever failover happened it's going to login page with server error.

Sample Connection String :

**Data Source=tcp:AGName,1234;Database=DB_name;User Id=loginname;Password=password;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;**

Comment: Queries/transactions in progress during the failover will be terminated. You'll need application retry logic to gracefully handle failover, when possible. See [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/step-4-connect-resiliently-sql-ado-net?view=sql-server-ver15). Drivers/frameworks may also do this transparently.

Comment: You already need some retry logic in you application on msg 1205 when transaction is chosen to be a deadlock victim anyway (isolation levels cannot save you from this), so the retry logic on AG failover abort can be supplemented there. Unfortunately you'll get msg 596 from a regular `KILL` too so it will be trickier to discern both failures (AG failover vs regular `KILL`).